# Getting NoProviderFoundException When try to implement "Hibernate Validator"

Tags: java, gradle, hibernate-validator

I am getting "Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath." this error when try to implement the Validation for my Entity (ProductInstance)

Here is the Usage

```
try {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        for (ConstraintViolation<ProductInstance> violation : validator.validate(product)) {
            genActResponse.addErrorMessage(violation.getMessage());
            genActResponse.addFailure();
            return genActResponse;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

Here is the **Dependency** in gradle.build

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-annotation-processor', version: '6.0.2.Final'
```

And here is the error I am getting

```
2018-12-03 20:22:12,420 WebErrorHandler                     ERROR - General exception
javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)
    at com.helpsystems.incn.access.service.DefaultProductInstanceService.updateProduct(DefaultProductInstanceService.java:200)
    at com.helpsystems.incn.server.ProductInstanceController.updateProduct(ProductInstanceController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Post your error stack trace ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add Hibernate validator. Add one of the following:

For Gradle, add:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.13.Final'
```

For Maven, add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You can adjust the version based on other dependencies versions'

Comment: Please note that in case of running in Java SE a dependency for an implementation of EL should also be added. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-uel

Comment: the same failure is with 


`dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: **'javax.el'**, version: '3.0.1-b09'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.13.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: **'hibernate-validator-annotation-processor'**, version: '6.0.13.Final'`

Comment: Post your POM file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SpringBoot, you can add the following library :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```